# Передача данных в слот не работает (через метод connect)

Tags: c++, qt5, сигналы-слоты

Есть вот такой код:

> test.h

```
class test : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
...............................................
public:
    test();
public slots:
    void txt();
signals:
    void ok();
};
```

> test.cpp

```
test::test(){
................................................
    connect(p, SIGNAL(clicked()), SIGNAL(ok()));
}

void test::txt(){
    l->setText("ok");
}
```

> main.cpp

```
....................................................
test a, b;

QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(ok()), &b, SLOT(txt()));
QObject::connect(&b, SIGNAL(ok()), &a, SLOT(txt()));
....................................................
```

Работает он замечательно. Но стоит добавить параметры передачи значений в слот как код перестает работать. Вот пример:

> test.h

```
class test : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
................................................
public:
    test();
public slots:
    void txt(QString);
signals:
    void ok(QString);
};
```

> test.cpp

```
test::test(){
......................................................
    connect(p, SIGNAL(clicked()), SIGNAL(ok("word")));
}

void test::txt(QString s){
    l->setText("ok");
}
```

> main.cpp

```
....................................................
test a, b;

QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(ok()), &b, SLOT(txt()));
QObject::connect(&b, SIGNAL(ok()), &a, SLOT(txt()));
....................................................
```

Этот код собирается но слот не отрабатывает, и почему то в редакторе строка:

```
connect(p, SIGNAL(clicked()), SIGNAL(ok("word")));
```

подчеркивается красным но в консоли ошибок нет. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: В `connect` нельзя задавать параметры слота. Параметр должен приходить из сигнала.

Comment: @kff ясно пасиб

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ответ kff из комментария:

> В connect нельзя задавать параметры слота. Параметр должен приходить
>   из сигнала

Дополню, что если сигнатура сигнала и слота не совпадает, либо необходимо выполнить дополнительные действия, то можно использовать [новый синтаксис](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax/ru) соединения сигналов и слотов, появившийся в Qt5, и lambda-выражения:

```
QObject::connect(p, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]() {
    Q_EMIT ok("word");
});
```